# Change the contents of youtube embended link

Tags: asp.net, youtube

This is a very simple complexive query that I have. I need the solution. I have a youtube link

```
 <----- width="480" height="350"><param name="movie"
 value="http://www.youtube.com/v/OORDOd6wRrE&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1"></param><param
 name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param
 name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><----
 src="http://www.youtube.com/v/OORDOd6wRrE&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1"
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always"
 allowfullscreen="true" width="480" height="350"><---><----->
```

this is the modified link. Well, my problem is, that I want to change the size of video, means in the whole string I want to replace **width="480"** with **width="250"** and **height="350"** with **height="250"**

I want to change these parameters programmatically using ASP.Net

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got my solution.

**Define one user define function**
private bool IsInt(string IntValue)
{
      try
      {
            int iValue = int.Parse(IntValue);
      }
      catch (Exception Ex) { return false;}
     return true;
}

```
    string str=txt_Links.Text;
    string lastNo = "";
    bool firstNoFound = false;
    for (int strIdx = 0; strIdx <= str.Length - 1; strIdx++)
    {
        if (IsInt(str.Substring(strIdx, 1)) == true)
        {
            lastNo = lastNo + str.Substring(strIdx, 1);
            firstNoFound = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (firstNoFound == true)
            {
                //Page.Title = lastNo;
                str = str.Replace("width=\"" + lastNo + "\"", "width=\"250\"").Replace("height=\"" + lastNo + "\"", "height=\"250\"");
                lastNo = "";
                firstNoFound = false;
            }
        }
    }

    Response.Write(str);
```

Comment: This is definitely `NOT` the way to do this! Use `regular expressions` like in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try your solution. That time, my problem solved by this code. So that put it on. This could be a wrong way but "IT IS 100% WORKING". Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

So what seems to be the problem?

This worked for me:

```
<object height="250" width="250">
    <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/OORDOd6wRrE"> 
    <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"> 
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque"> 
    <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/OORDOd6wRrE" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque" height="250" width="250"> 
</object>
```

However you should change the `height` and `width` according to the `H/W ratio` in order for the movie not to become distorted.

**EDIT:**

After seeing OPs answer I think I understand what he's trying to do. For this my suggestion is to use `regular expressions` like so:

```
temp = Regex.Replace(strInput, "width=\"\d*\"", "width=\"250\"");
result = Regex.Replace(temp, "height=\"\d*\"", "height=\"250\"");
```

Also, check out the following tutorial: [Regular Expressions in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
I know that, I want to change these parameters by programmatically in ASP.Net.

Thanks

Comment: You don't make the source of your problem clear enough. However, it's as simple as: `myLabel.Text = "<object height='250' width='250'><param name='movie' value='http://www.youtube.com/v/OORDOd6wRrE'> <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'><param name='wmode' value='opaque'><embed src='http://www.youtube.com/v/' + myVideoID type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowfullscreen='true' wmode='opaque' height='250' width='250'></object>";`